# How to extract a single image from the output of the DiscreteWaveletTransform[]?

Tags: image, wavelet-analysis

So, I use the following code to carry out the discrete wavelet transform on an image of Lena. I am interested in then doing some changes to a single image out of the obtained 4. How do I extract any of the images? How do I then put it back into an object which I can then carry out the inverse wavelet transform on?

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];

dwd = DiscreteWaveletTransform[img, HaarWavelet[], 2];

WaveletImagePlot[dwd, Automatic,ImageAdjust[ImageAdjust[#], {0.01, 0.2, 1.9}]&]
```

[image]

Comment: Did you look at the "Properties and Relations" section of the docs for `WaveletImagePlot[]`? It's explained there how to obtain separate images instead of a hierarchical grid.

Comment: I must have missed it. Thank you @J.M., I have looked into now and realized that I missed it.

Answer (score 2):

As I noted in the comments, the docs mention how to obtain the component images used in `WaveletImagePlot[]`:

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
dwd = DiscreteWaveletTransform[img, HaarWavelet[], 2];

dwd[Automatic, "Image"]
```

[image: component images]

I'm not sure how to apply `ImageAdjust[]` to these component images to be consistent with the result of `WaveletImagePlot[]`, however.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [ImageTake](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageTake.html)?

```
img = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
dwd = DiscreteWaveletTransform[img, HaarWavelet[], 2];
wip = WaveletImagePlot[dwd, Automatic,ImageAdjust[ImageAdjust[#], {0.01, 0.2, 1.9}] &]

ImageTake[wip, {20, 300}, {20, 300}]
```

which gives:

[image: lena]

Comment: Thank you for helping me out here @JeRut. This allows me to extract the parts I am interested in carrying out any processing on. Still the question remains, after doing the processing, how do I put that processed part of the image back and get its inverse DWT?